# How to extract the credentials sent through NetworkCredentials class in WCF Application?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a project where the credentials are sent from Windows mobile(Compact Framework) through the **NetworkCredentials** object. 
I need to extract the credentials from the Header and authenticate against the LDAP server in the WCF application. Is there a way to do it ? Any suggestions would be welcomed !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract credentials, pass the NetworkCredential object direclty to LDAP:

```
public static bool login(string domain, System.Net.NetworkCredential cred)
{
    try
    {
        LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection(domain);
        conn.Bind(cred);
        return true; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paolo : I just passed the NetworkCredential as input to the Login method, I was able to extract the userName but not able to extract the password. I also tried with securePassword but no luck :( ..